# react native geolocation not asking user permission on android emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

Hi Im using the below code to successfully get user location, but in the android emulator it is not asking user if they want to share their location (even after I reinstall the app).

The code works which is great....but I really would like the standard alert to appear which says "are you sure you want to share your location with the app"

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (pos) => {
          console.log(pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think location permission not show again event you reinstall app because phone still remember permissions granted for app. You can check app have permission granted in Android Setting with App (https://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/).

Maybe this code can help you

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

async function getLocation() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        'title': 'App',
        'message': 'are you sure you want to share your location with the app ?'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // permission granted
      // do code get location here.
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (pos) => {
          console.log(pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude);
        })
    } else {
      // permission denied
      console.log("GPS permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can go into settings for app to reset location preferences....dont need to reinstall app.  Also the above code is not helpful because (a) the popup that appears cannot be (easily) dismissed by user as it doesnt have the required buttons (neutral/negative/positive) and (b) regardless of what user chooses from the request method they will be asked again once they hit navigator.geolocation.  Very odd.  Thanks anyway for your input